# Job and workers, pattern / design

Tags: design-patterns, object

I have x number of worker classes which all implement a specific interface, i have a job descriptions 
Each job description States the different worker classes that should execute to complete the job 
Am I smelling a strategy pattern here?

All workers share some configuration  data so I think I should have a seperate configuration classes that I can be passed into the constructor at worker creation

AM I walking down the right path?

*EDIT*

more high level details

- the job description specifies the different workers that needs to run to produce a sample file.
- each worker deals with a specific set of data domains
- all workers share the same output generation class to produce file(s) that are structurally same.
- there can be y number of job definitions and x number of workers so

> y(1) uses x(1),x(2),x(3)
>
> y(2) uses x(2),x(3),x(4)

i could have a JobFactory that returns a collection of the required worker classes and then iterate through the collection while invoking the worker execute method.

just looking for more ideas/opinions.

Comment: Is each and every worker is assigned to a single or multiple jobs? Is there a composition between the worker object and job object. Please provide more details.

Comment: @Maxood i edited my question added more info. hope this clarifies. thanks for your help

Comment: If both jobs y(1) and y(2) are created, do they share instances of workers x(2) and x(3) or do they both get their own instances?

Comment: good question @BartvanIngenSchenau at the moment the implementation language will not support such parallelism, if y(1) and y(2) were to start at the same time they will be independent processes.Therefore will have their own instance of the worker.

Comment: @DevZer0: Having separate worker instances for each job will make your life easier (unless the workers are not a pure software construct, but tied to physical machines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design that springs to mind for me is to have a `Job` class, which holds the recipe for the job and a collection of abstract `Worker` instances.
To create the concrete workers required by the recipe, I would use a `WorkerFactory` (creating one worker per request).

The responsibility of the `Job` class is to create the string of workers needed for a job and to execute those workers.

Comment: How should the common data be shared among the workers? referencing a instance of the job inside the worker? or passed into the worker at creation as a ConfigObject? (i have about 10 different parameters, so passing them individually can look bit ugly)

Comment: @DevZer0: I would probably go for the ConfigObject, although the Job object can fulfill that role as well.